# Is there a better/cleaner way to assign values based on the result of radio buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 radio buttons all grouped inside a group box in a WinForms project. Currently, I am checking which button is checked and assigning values using the following if/else statement, similar to the below example

```
        if (rb1.Checked)
        {
            selectedButton = 1;
            selectedButtonText = rb1.Text;
        }
        else if (rb2.Checked)
        {
            selectedButton = 2;
            selectedButtonText = rb2.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedButton = 3;
            selectedButtonText = rb3.Text;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(selectedButtonText);
```

This doesn't look very efficient or scalable. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `LINQ` with `Controls` to get the checked one.

```
var radio = groupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);

switch(radio.Name)
{
    case "rb1":
        selectedButton = 1;
        selectedButtonText = rb1.Text;
        break;
    case "rb2":
        selectedButton = 2;
        selectedButtonText = rb2.Text;
        break;
    default:
        selectedButton = 3;
        selectedButtonText = rb3.Text;
        break;
}

Console.WriteLine(selectedButtonText);
```

However, I think you're best if you use something like `ComboBox` instead of the radio buttons.

Comment: You're right, combobox is definitely the way to go here. Your solution is nice though.

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note for you.  It would probably be more efficient to use the `Checked_Change` handler.  The main caveat is that both the checked and the unchecked will trigger this event.  but since the unchecked is handled first, it's a simple matter of returning if the `sender` isn't checked.

Since the radiobuttons are actually numbered you don't need the switch block once you have the checked radiobutton identified.

Something like this would work:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    if(!rb.Checked)
    {
        return;
    }
    selectedButton = rb.Name.Last() - '0';
    selectedButtonText = rb.Text;
}
```